# How can I get current controller in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to get current page controller in yii2? 
How can I achieve this in Yii2?

In Yii 1.0

```
Yii::app()->controller->action->id
```

Yii2 ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

use this code

```
Yii::$app->controller->id
```

Comment: if i print_r pr(Yii::$app->controller); then i got empty array

Answer (score 19):

this may help...:)

```
<?php echo Yii::$app->controller->id; //current controller id ?>


<?php echo Yii::$app->controller->action->id; //current controller action id ?>
```

Comment: you mean layout?. its global you can use.

Comment: No, I want to use this function in on `beforeRequest` key of return array at file "backend/config/main.php"

Answer (score 8):

From view and layout files, you may use

```
<?= $this->context->id //controller id ?>
<?= $this->context->action->id //action id ?>
```