# Yii2 get any controller->Id

Tags: controller, yii2

How get any controller->id from current controller,like if I in the default site controller and I write `Yii::$app->controller->id/index` it gives me the `site/index`,but if I have another controller like named student(and I am in the site controller) how can I redirected to `student/index`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  redirect

```
 return $this->redirect('/your-controller/your-actionindex',302);
```

or simply without return

```
$this->redirect('/user/index',302);
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller Id :

```
$this->id
```

Here $this refers to controller.

And For getting action id :

```
$this->action->id
```

If you are using out of controller then

```
Yii::app()->controller->id
```

or

```
Yii::app()->getController()->getId()
```

Comment: It's Yii2 not Yii1.

Comment: But its return controller id in Yii2 also
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27796371/how-can-i-get-current-controller-in-yii2] ( For Ref.)